# Why is type constraint not always enforced when it is set to class?

Tags: c#, generics, type-constraints

I have this code:

```
void Foo<T>(T x) {} where T:class

interface IBar {}

IBar GetBar() {...}
```

Despite the implicit type constraint set to class, I am still able to abstract the call and pass an interface:

```
Foo<IBar>(GetBar());
```

Why is the type constraint is not enforced in this case?

But, if I use this construction:

```
void Doo<T>(T x) {
    Foo<T>(x);
}
```

then the compiler will throw an error and complain that type 'T' must be a reference type, which is expected.

Comment: In the second construction, you don't have the `where` condition.

Comment: I think this has to do with boxing, I had thought that using a struct that implements the interface would show the error, but surprisingly it does not. [This was unexpected](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TZMVTi), I'm guessing that `T` is boxed to an `object` (or its interface type) which then satisfies the `where T : class` constraint.

Comment: @RonBeyer
`IL_0009:  ldloc.0     // myStruct` 
`IL_000A:  box         UserQuery.MyStruct`
`IL_000F:  call        UserQuery+Program.Foo<IFace>`
Seems like a correct assessment of how/why the struct worked.

Comment: @JonathonChase Thanks, I didn't go so far as to examine the IL, but it seemed probable.

Comment: since you can't instantiate an interface by itself. It has to be a class which implements the interface. So it makes sense.

Comment: @RonBeyer how does this have anything to do with boxing? The OP's example has nothing to do with boxing, but in your example since you are specifying type explicitly, the struct is obviously boxed because it is passed as `IFace` to the method, and `IFace` is a reference type, it's just like if you pass a struct to a method that takes object. If you change call to this: `Foo(myStruct);` then you will get a compile error.

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces are reference types. The `where : class` constraint doesn't mean `T` must be a class, it says `T` must be a refence type.

Answer (score -2):

Actually, the type constraint *is* enforced. You appear to be thinking that an interface isn't a class. But an interface is just a type of class: technically, it is an abstract class with the further constraint that there can be no concrete members.

[The doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) states this for `where T : class`:

> The type argument must be a reference type. This constraint applies also to any class, interface, delegate, or array type.

Comment: An interface isn't a class. Interfaces are distinct types from classes both in C# and in CIL terminology. The fact that the `class` keyword is used here doesn't change that.

Comment: `class` constraint constrains to a *reference type* not to a *class*. An interface is most definitely not an abstract class.

Comment: From Microsoft's own definition of an abstract class: "An abstract class cannot be instantiated. The purpose of an abstract class is to provide a common definition of a base class that multiple derived classes can share. For example, a class library may define an abstract class that is used as a parameter to many of its functions, and require programmers using that library to provide their own implementation of the class by creating a derived class." This all holds equally true for interfaces, albeit with different implementation semantics. That's why the constraint applies to all of them IMO.

Comment: A further example from Microsoft: "The abstract modifier indicates that the thing being modified has a missing or incomplete implementation." Also true of interfaces. So, your assertions to the contrary, I don't find the evidence in C# or CIL terminology that shows the distinction in any sense other than syntactical semantics, beyond that the interface is a subset of the abstract class.

Comment: Now, to support my assertion that interfaces are technically a subset of abstract classes, this is the approach taken by UML metaclass semantics: all classes (meaning concrete classes, abstract classes and interfaces) are instances of the abstract `Classifier` metaclass, which has an `isAbstract` attribute. Abstract classes and interfaces both set that attribute to true, while interfaces have the further constraint that all members must be both public and abstract.

Comment: @BobRodes That doesn't hold equally true for interfaces. Classes cannot derive from interfaces, classes can only implement interfaces. While I don't doubt others define interface as a type of class, they aren't in C# or CIL. For C#, see "Class types" in the language spec, which references "Classes", which says the only definitions of class types are those with the keyword `class`. That excludes interfaces. For CIL, type definitions are divided into "interface definitions" for "interface types" and "class definitions" for "class types" (including value types), see ECMA 335 I.8.9.

Comment: @hvd Thank you for pointing me to the relevant documentation. While I take your point, and I realize that C# and CIL draw a syntactic distinction between abstract classes and interfaces, I submit that the distinctions drawn between interfaces and  abstract classes wherein all the members are themselves abstract are semantic rather than substantive. I further submit that the distinction between deriving from an abstract class wherein all the members are abstract and implementing interfaces is also a semantic one. One which most language specifications make, to be sure, but still a semantic one.

Comment: @hvd I would be very interested to find out how C# actually implements classes and interfaces under the hood. I suspect that they both derive from some sort of Classifier metaclass, much in the same way that the UML metamodel specifies them. That's been kind of what I've been getting at here.